# Change all SBT target directories to the outside of the source

Tags: scala, sbt

I am having a hard time running SBT in a "read-only" directory (directory I have permissions but I cannot/shouldn't write).

I want basically to move all the target directories to another location.

Half the problem is solved with:

```
target := file("</full/path/to/new/location>")
```

but it is still creating target directories inside the `project/*` directory.

I would also like this to be done in the run command, not by changing the sbt files.
The current command I am using is:

```
sbt 'set target := file("</full/path/to/new/location>")' compile
```

Adding some kind of system wide sbt configuration would be a possibility, but I also could not make it work.

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Comment: To configure the project build build, you would need to change target in `project/build.sbt` - do you have at least one time access to change your build's build?

Comment: Another (better?) option perhaps is to use an entire fresh directory and just symlink to your sources and resources. Would that work?

Comment: Interact with the filesystem is not ideal

Answer (score 1):

So here is my suggestion using symlinks:

```
$ mkdir -p have_access/project
$ ln -sr read_only/src have_access/
$ ln -sr read_only/build.sbt have_access/
$ ln -sr read_only/project/build.properties have_access/project/
$ cd have_access
$ sbt test
```

Comment: Interact with the filesystem is not ideal, at last resort it would be valid to have system wide configs outside the source folder, but I also did not found how to do it.